# Mute Button for all MediaElement in WP8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to create a mute button for my app at MainPage.xaml , so when i click it every mediaelement in other xaml pages also mute

I use a button to control this bool variable (which i put it in MainPage.xaml)

```
public static bool isMuted { get; set; }
```

and in every mediaelement in apps i use this binding

```
<MediaElement x:Name="MESong" IsMuted="{Binding IsMuted}"/>
```

but this binding 's not working ?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<MediaElement x:Name="MESong" IsMuted="{Binding isMuted}"/>
```

You are using **isMuted** Property so you need to bind that.

Comment: oh it's my mistake, but change it to isMuted didn't solve problem, but i've found solution, thanks anw ^^

Answer (score 0):

update: I don't know why but when i updated the code and implemented INotifyPropertyChanged, it's work :|

```
private bool _isMuted;
public bool IsMuted
{
    get { return _isMuted; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _isMuted)
        {
            _isMuted = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsMuted");
        }
    }
}
```